# 'no such option' using OptionParser

Tags: python

#
Edit: I did not choose to start Ipython with the --pylab argument. I have python(x,y) installed so maybe that is the problem?

Edit2: I'm on Windows. I start the IDE from the python(x,y) console. Problem also occurs when I start Visual Studio (i'm using PTVS). Problem doesn't occur when I directly start IDLE and run the example there.

Trying to run the following code from Python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html

```
from optparse import OptionParser
[...]
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename",
                  help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE")
parser.add_option("-q", "--quiet",
                  action="store_false", dest="verbose", default=True,
                  help="don't print status messages to stdout")
```

I get the following error:

```
In [55]: (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

Usage: -c [options]

-c: error: no such option: --pylab
To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
```

I'm new to python and not really sure whats going on here. Curious why the error is referencing pylab? Seems odd. Was wondering if anybody else had run into a similar problem. Here is the traceback in case it helps:

```
In [56]: %tb
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-9900fd0b7216> in <module>()
----> 1 (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

C:\Python27\lib\optparse.pyc in parse_args(self, args, values)
   1399             stop = self._process_args(largs, rargs, values)
   1400         except (BadOptionError, OptionValueError), err:
-> 1401             self.error(str(err))
   1402 
   1403         args = largs + rargs

C:\Python27\lib\optparse.pyc in error(self, msg)
   1581         """
   1582         self.print_usage(sys.stderr)
-> 1583         self.exit(2, "%s: error: %s\n" % (self.get_prog_name(), msg))
   1584 
   1585     def get_usage(self):

C:\Python27\lib\optparse.pyc in exit(self, status, msg)
   1571         if msg:
   1572             sys.stderr.write(msg)
-> 1573         sys.exit(status)
   1574 
   1575     def error(self, msg):

SystemExit: 2
```

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough information to make this reproducible -- in particular, you don't show where you're defining the `--pylab` option (assuming that you actually do so -- if not, that's the problem), or the exact command line you're invoking with. Ideally, provide a cut-down reproducer which can be used standing alone, with no external dependencies or elided code.

Comment: Actually, nowhere have I defined the --pylab option anywhere. I'm using python(x,y), maybe there is an issue with defaults? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `--pylab` isn't a default. Where do you get the impression that it's supposed to be one?

Comment: ...if you aren't passing `--pylab` to the program you're running, but it's being added by something else, then the place to start is with your shell -- to check for shell functions, aliases, &c. doing that addition for you to be "helpful". Running `set -x` on the shell command line before starting your program is a good place to begin.

Comment: (This is part of why showing the invocation itself would have made for a more complete question -- the obvious way to interpret the error is that you're running `./your-program --pylab`, without having a handler for `--pylab`).

Comment: Your edit has clarified this a little -- it tells us you *aren't* adding `--pylab` intentionally -- but it doesn't show us how you *are* running your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OptParse will read from sys.argv by default. You've started ipython with the arg --pylab which doesn't exist in your optparse setup, hence the error.

You can pass an empty string to `parse_args('')` to test the defaults.